# How is it possible that the output of the following code is true?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
this.someService.findDevices()
          .subscribe((segments) => {
            this.segments = Array.from(segments.segments);
            this.packs.forEach((pack) => {
              pack.segments = Array.from(segments.segments);
              pack.segments[0].devices[0].selected = true; //if commented, output is FALSE
              console.log(this.segments[0].devices[0]); // shows TRUE
            });
          });
```

I created a method where I'm trying to add the `segments` array to each pack in `this.packs`.
I am creating a new array using `Array.from()` but for some reason when I set the `pack.segments[0].devices[0]` to TRUE, `this.segments[0].devices[0]` is changing to true as well.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You're making a *shallow* copy of the array, but the new array still has references to the original objects.

Comment: You'll have to clone those segments, at the moment, you are just copying around references to the same segments

Comment: I'm guessing you can reproduce this without the service -- this seems like a purely JavaScript question "Why is my array mutating?" Also, your question would be improved greatly if the code was actually runnable, with 0 external dependencies or unknown variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a **shallow copy** of the `segments` array, which **does not clone** the `devices` array inside it.

To do a deep clone and make your code work as expected try the below.

```js
 pack.segments = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(segments.segments))
```

***NOTE:*** The above will not not work if you have any circular reference within the array

Answer (score 0):

Create a top-level boolean variable inside your function called `isSelected` and set it appropriately. Then do your loop. If any one item changes switches, `isSelected` will then be set and return proper boolean value.